# OpenAI API error: "TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor at Object."

Tags: javascript, openai-api, gpt-4

I am using the OpenAI API in JavaScript. Below is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const OpenAI_Api = process.env.OpenAIApi || 'Mykey';

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

const configuration = new Configuration({
          apiKey: OpenAI_Api
        });

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const createChatCompletion = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: 'gpt-4.0',
      messages: [
        { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' },
        { role: 'user', content: 'Who won the world series in 2020?' },
        { role: 'assistant', content: 'The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020.' },
        { role: 'user', content: 'Where was it played?' },
        { role: 'assistant', content: 'The World Series was played in Arlington, Texas at the Globe Life Field.' },
      ],
    });

    console.log(response.choices[0].message.content); // Display the generated response
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating chat completion:', error);
  }
};

createChatCompletion();
```

It is saved in `chatgpt.js`. However, when I run `node chatgpt.js`, I receive an error.

```
const configuration = new Configuration({
                      ^

TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\OneDrive - The University of Nottingham\ESR1\work\Knowledge graph\doctorai_ui_gpt3_test\chatgpt.js:7:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Which version of `openai` are you using? Since [the implementation got changed](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217) somewhat recently

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I am using the 4.26.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to use worked with the OpenAI Node.js SDK <`v4`.

As you said, you're using `v4.26.0`, so the following is the correct initialization:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env['OPENAI_API_KEY'],
});
```

But you also made some other mistakes:

- using the wrong method name (i.e., `createChatCompletion`, which works with <`v4`)
- using an incorrect model name (i.e., `gpt-4.0`, which does not exist)

The following is the correct full code:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env['OPENAI_API_KEY'],
});

const createChatCompletion = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: 'gpt-4',
      messages: [
        { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' },
        { role: 'user', content: 'Who won the world series in 2020?' },
        { role: 'assistant', content: 'The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020.' },
        { role: 'user', content: 'Where was it played?' },
        { role: 'assistant', content: 'The World Series was played in Arlington, Texas at the Globe Life Field.' },
      ],
    });

    console.log(response.choices[0].message.content);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating chat completion:', error);
  }
};

createChatCompletion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is based on v3 but you're using v4. [This comes with some changes](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).

First of, the initialization is a bit different, there is no use of a `Configuration` object anymore. Furthermore the `openai.createChatCompletion` is moved to `openai.chat.completions.create`.

I've reflected these changed in the code you've provided.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import OpenAI from 'openai';

dotenv.config();

const OpenAI_Api = process.env.OpenAIApi || 'Mykey';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: OpenAI_Api
});

const createChatCompletion = async () => {
  try {
    const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-4",
      messages: [
        { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' },
        { role: 'user', content: 'Who won the world series in 2020?' },
        { role: 'assistant', content: 'The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020.' },
        { role: 'user', content: 'Where was it played?' },
        { role: 'assistant', content: 'The World Series was played in Arlington, Texas at the Globe Life Field.' },
      ],
    });
    console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0].message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating chat completion:', error);
  }
};

createChatCompletion();
```

Comment: Yes, you missed `gpt-4.0`. ;)